# Can MySQL have one file per database?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I like the fact that a Microsoft Access `.mdb` file contains a complete database in a single file, so for example `foo.mdb` may contain all the data, table structures and queries for one database.

I want to move over to MySQL. I understand that MySQL can use many file structures. Can MySQL replicate the single file model of one database = one file?

Comment: [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) databases are single files, though if you want MySQL, SQLite may not be as powerful or feature-rich as your requirements demand.

Comment: I do not see SQLite as an improvement on MS Access in this case. If your users are editing locally, MS Access offers a very quick front-end development, whereas you will have to have additional packages for forms, reports etc with SQLite and MySQL. Why do you wish to move from MS Access, it seems to be the right choice for your requirement?

Comment: I'm looking at moving from MS Access to MySQL because I'm moving a site from MS IIS to Linux. I'm currently running IIS and connecting to the .mdb files using "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" in ASP Classic. I'm trying to work out my best option in the Linux/PHP world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: it depends on the storage engine.

All dbs managed by innodb storage engine are stored in one file. If you have 3 innodb dbs on the server, they all are going to be stored in one file. This can be changed however with innodb_file_per_table

MYISAM storage engine stores each table of the db in two separate files: data and index.

Why do you need a single file anyway? MySQL has a built-in replication mechanism, you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Regarding "innodb_file_per_table", that implies file-per-table not file-per-database, yes?

Comment: Yes, for more info see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

Comment: "Why do you need a single file anyway?" It's a handy model that my non-techy customers can understand.

Comment: MySQL is supposed to run on a (web)server. Non-techy customers will probably never even see it. Why do they care? If you are trying to make MySQL installation portable, you are going to run into a lot of problems except db being stored in multiple files. MySQL is simply not built to work this way.

Comment: They see it because they are custodians of their own data. They edit their database locally then upload the file to their live site.

Comment: Then MySQL is definitely not you choice. You should try SQLite. It is similar to ms access because it has a standalone gui app to edit the dbs(unlike mysql) and db is stored in one file and does not need any actions except copying(unlike mysql) to work on a different machine.